# Query is neglecting one of where clause, any idea why it is happening?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `activity` and `users`. I am trying to fetch data by using multiple where clauses.

```
SELECT SUM(activity.step_points) AS s_points
, `activity`.`user_id`
, `users`.`id`
, `users`.`app_id`
, `users`.`country_id`
FROM `activity` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `activity`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`is_active` = 1 AND 
`users`.`is_test_account` = 0 AND 
`users`.`app_id` = 3 AND 
`users`.`country_id` = 1 AND 
`users`.`phone` NOT LIKE "%000000%" OR 
`users`.`phone` IS NULL AND 
`users`.`is_subscribed` = 1 AND 
(`users`.`email` NOT LIKE "%@mycompanyname.net" OR 
 `users`.`email` IS NULL) AND 
YEAR(`activity`.`created_at`) = "2021" AND 
MONTH(`activity`.`created_at`) = "06" 
GROUP BY `activity`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY `s_points` DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

But I think `users.country_id = 1` is getting neglected. You can see I want only rows that belong to country id 1. But I am getting country id 2, 3 too.

[image: table screenshot]

Why is it happening?

Comment: You need to be careful when you have a mix of AND with OR in where clauses.  Try and use brackets to ensure they are interpreted correctly.

Comment: @NigelRen so true

Comment: Does `so true` mean your problem is now solved?

Comment: @JamesZ yes that solved my problem

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly use parentheses in the `WHERE` clause so the `OR` does not dominate over the `AND`s:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM activity a JOIN 
     users u
     ON u.id = a.id 
WHERE u.is_active = 1 AND 
      u.is_test_account = 0 AND 
      u.app_id = 3 AND 
      u.country_id = 1 AND 
      (u.phone NOT LIKE '%000000%' OR u.phone IS NULL) AND 
      u.is_subscribed = 1 AND 
      (u.email NOT LIKE '%@mycompanyname.net OR u.email IS NULL) AND 
      (a.created_at >= '2021-01-01' AND a.created_at < '2022-01-01'
```

Note the other changes to the code:

- You are filtering on both tables, so an outer join is not appropriate.  The `WHERE` clause turns it into an inner join anyway.
- Table aliases make the code easier to write and to read.
- All the backticks just make the code harder to write and read and are not needed.
- SQL's standard delimiter for strings is single quotes.  Use them unless you have a good reason for preferring double quotes.
- For date comparisons, it can be faster to avoid functions, hence the change for the year comparison.  This helps the optimizer.